# type and extensions in Linux

Tags: linux

I read that Linux systems use something called "MIME type" to figure out what the file type is, then, do we have to save programs with extensions, when we create then in linux? ex: programs such as "helloworld.c" or "Newfile.html" when we create them, do we have append the .c or .html or just leave it and it would be handled automatically?

Comment: Why even use file names at all? Why not just addresses on the disk? Because us computer users (humans) are better with names and words and letters.  The file foo could be a binary, or a plain text copy of the recipe your grandma uses for cookies, or C source code.  But to us humans, foo (or foo.exe on windows) vs foo.txt vs foo.c makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Its less "Mimetype" than [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). In the case of both these files though, they're likely to be plain text files than anything else.

For most part *programs* will not care what the extension is. Your *web server* might use an extension,mimetype (or part of the file) to decide what a file is and how to handle it, but the OS will not, unlike windows.

When in doubt, add an extension, then work as if the extension is not there. If nothing else, it tells you at a glance *what the file is*.

You can also use the [file command](http://www.linfo.org/file_command.html) to check what a file is.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to accomplish. You do not have to use file extensions as the system should detect the files type automatically (at least for the most common ones)

Extensions mostly help in determining what file type you are looking at while browsing filesystem or when automating work through scripts / shell commands - like for example moving all html files to another folder using command like:

```
mv *.html some_destination_folder
```